# how to install unsigned .apk on mobile phone

Tags: android

i had made a application in eclipse and android sdk and make a .apk (go to "android tool" and export "unsigned apk") so i had a .apk file and then i send it to sd card of mobile  and tap on the .apk file for installing it on mobile but one error message comes that  " application can not be install"  so now how to install it on my devise my devise version is 2.2  and i make application using target "target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:7" now how to install it. i also give permission on mobile that install third party application.
my manifest file are given below...thanks for help in adv.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.androidpeople.tab"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
 <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"

  <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity android:name=".SplashScreen"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
       </activity>

             <activity android:name="currentlocmap" />
             <activity android:name="filter" />
             <activity android:name="keywordsearch" />
                     <activity android:name="Artistspacedetailview" />
                         <activity android:name="loadingimage" />
                         <activity android:name="keywordpagetabs" />
                         <activity android:name="filterpagetabs" />
                          <activity android:name="artistspacedetailviewTab" />
             <activity android:name="filtersearchresultparsing" />
             <activity android:name="keywordresulttab" />
             <activity android:name="filterpageresulttab" />
              <activity android:name="artspacedetailShowingNow" />
              <activity android:name="detailviewshowingnowTab" />



               </application>
                  <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"
                android:largeScreens="true"
                android:normalScreens="true"
                android:smallScreens="true" />
                   </manifest> 


    default.properties

     **target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:7**
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are planning on testing your app before you sign it. 
As far as I know, non-signed apps on an android can be tested by adding a debug - notification in the manifest file by adding android:debuggable="true" to the  element.

[Click here to Read More](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html).

Hope this Helps you!

Comment: diploma is there any need for installation of google usb driver ??i am using LG 2.2 v mobile phone.

Comment: Nope the google usb driver is only for the Google Based phones such as NEXUS etc. You would only be needing to install any form of PC-SUITE that you got with the Mobile Phone. Else you could download a driver from the LG website.

Comment: This is unrelated. You still can't run unsigned apps with `debuggable = true`. With Eclipse/ADT it automatically signs your app with a debug key when debugging. This might be what you're thinking of.

Comment: @kabuko: It is a fact that Eclipse/ADT Signs ur app with a Debug key. I just wanted to say that if he's testing his app , Full further testing can be done on the on a real platform instead of an EMULATOR. and when i mentioned (non-signed) I meant if the OP didn't want to sign in with his Key.

Answer (score 2):

As the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html) say, you **must** sign your APK for it to be installed. Just go ahead and sign it, it doesn't take anything special, you don't have to have a Market account or anything like that. All the 
directions you need should be in the link I included.

Comment: @ Kabuko means i go to android tool and choose "export signed application package"? and fill it whole?then i can install it??

Comment: Yes. From Eclipse you can use the ADT Export Wizard and select Export Signed Application Package. Just follow the wizard, creating a new keystore, etc. as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Unsigned applications can be installed on device only in condition that the device is connected to the development machine or else not.

TO install the APK explicitly, it has to be signed.

Comment: Nope, unsigned applications can not be installed. When you debug your application from within eclipse your application is signed by debug key which automatically created by SDK.